# Initialize nodejs module once, use many times

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to pull out some code into my node.js app into a module. However, I'm running into an issue: the module requires some configuration that's generated during app startup. Is there an elegant way to initialize the module (by passing in the configuration) the first time it's require()d, but subsequent require() calls don't re-run the initialization?

I could do something like have an init() function that I call manually the first time but never again, but that seems clunky and I'm wondering if there's a better pattern for it.

edit: Here's what I'm doing right now, which feels clunky since doThings() isn't going to work if init() hasn't been called.

```
var config;

function doThings() {
    // use config variable for something
}

function init(newConfig) {
    config = newConfig;
}

module.exports = {
    doThings: doThings,
    init: init
}
```

Comment: `require` does its own form of caching, so I don't think it should be running the initialization code multiple times in most cases anyway

Comment: `require` [runs your module code only one time](https://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/200652/please-explain-object-versioning-in-the-nodejs-module-system/201212#201212) per named module. Does the impact your question at all? I understand generally what your problem is, but some example code might be helpful to help me understand the specifics of your situation.

Comment: I added an example in the question.