# How to run Node.js module initialization properly

Tags: node.js

In a Node.js module, I need to run some initialization code, some code to be run only once, to parse a YAML config file
on my application startup.

As a Node.js novice, I noticed that modules are loaded once, and only once (and that's very fine like that). I mean:

```
// ./mymodule.js

console.log('mymodule.js was run');
```

... displays the given message only once, even if `./mymodule.js` was needed in multiple loaded modules. And that's fine.

So, for my init code, I can imagine to implement it simply like that:

```
// ./mymodule.js

function mymodule_init()
    // Parse my config file
    // ...
    // Done
}

// Run my init:
mymodule_init();

console.log('mymodule.js was run');
```

But is it the right way to run my initialization code? Isn't there a more regular way to do it, like subscribing to
a kind of '`module_init`' event, which would guarantee that my init code would be run once and only once?

*Note*: I found this SO link about the question : [Initialize nodejs module once, use many times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25314966/initialize-nodejs-module-once-use-many-times), but there's no really frank answer about it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Node.js documention on the subject of module caching](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_caching) states:

> Multiple calls to require('foo') may not cause the module code to be
>   executed multiple times. This is an important feature. With it,
>   "partially done" objects can be returned, thus allowing transitive
>   dependencies to be loaded even when they would cause cycles.

So I don't see anything wrong with initialization code executed directly in a module. I am doing this in several Node.js apps, as you indicate, like so:

```
// ./mymodule.js

function mymodule_init()
    // Parse my config file
    // ...
    // Done
}

// Run my init:
mymodule_init();

console.log('mymodule.js was run');
```

Answer (score 4):

Your question will mostly have opinionated answers, but anyway.

I usually use a singleton class for this kind of work.

Something like

```
// config.js

function Config() {
   this.config = parseYAML("./path/to/yaml-file.yaml");   
}

Config.prototype.get = function( property ) {
   return this.config[property];
}

module.exports = new Config();
```

And in your app or modules

```
// app.js

const config = require( "./config.js" );

console.log( config.get("some-config-property") );
```

Most of the modules either use this or an anonymous function, which is called immediately e.g.

```
module.exports = (function() {
   return parseYAML("./path/to/yaml-file.yaml");
})();
```

Both cases you will do it right, so it actually doesn't matter so much, as long as your code is readable.

Comment: Your answer is working well and is better written than my example, but it doesn't really respond to the question, I mean, can I formally trust the Node.js cache to run this code only once?